# startup to desktop and then enter password

Tags: password

Is there a way where we can startup to desktop then its going to ask for a password (like how you enter passwords for user accounts on windows) instead of the raspberry pi starting up with password then bring us to the command line? just so that the user doesn't have to enter 'startx' to get to the desktop gui.

Comment: if you have a working solution, you may answer your own question, that way your knowledge will be available for other people.

Comment: + this this question will be answered instead of remaining unanswered.

Comment: ppumkin - yeap doing that now, when i tried to answer my own question, said i had to wait for 8 hours. anyway, i'm answering it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the system to boot to the desktop but then edit the file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and look for the line that reads:

```
autologin-user=pi
```

and you change this to read

```
#autologin-user=pi
```

Found it on http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=69448